# Inaccurate georeferencing when plotting raster files using rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio, visualisation, plotting

I am trying to develop a plot of a raster image with a background map. I used `rasterio` for reading the raster file and `contextily` for obtaining the background map following [this tutorial](https://pysal.org/scipy2019-intermediate-gds/deterministic/gds2-rasters).

The plotted map is wrong in terms of geocoordinates. To elaborate, the raster is not aligning with the feature it is representing (river) webmap. How can I fix this? What is going wrong?

[Google colab file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gEJLrVmyXAaeR6JKW6f0vsk43heS1cIx?usp=sharing) with a reproducible example.

```
pth_raster = '/content/raster_data_resampled.tif'
data, out_path, affine = reproject_raster(in_path=pth_raster, band_to_read=1, out_folder="./raster_temp", destination_crs='epsg:3857') #<-- for webmap epsg:3857
src = rasterio.open(out_path)
src.crs

>CRS.from_epsg(3857)

basemap, basemap_extent = ctx.bounds2img(*src.bounds)

import matplotlib.cm as cm
my_cmap = cm.jet
my_cmap.set_under('k', alpha=0)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(basemap, extent=basemap_extent)
plt.imshow(src.read(1), extent=basemap_extent, cmap=my_cmap, interpolation='none', clim=[-900, 1e5]) #<-- clim for removing no data (-9999) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `basemap_extent` is different from `src.bounds`.

```
src_extent = src.bounds.left, src.bounds.right, src.bounds.bottom, src.bounds.top

print(basemap_extent)
print(src_extent)
```

> ```
> (-10610682.518435026,-10604567.556172213, 3464737.618110468, 3470852.5803732835),
> (-10610046.586014193, -10604771.70913406, 3465296.2656639265, 3470571.1425440577)
> ```

Try passing `src_extent` to `plt.imshow`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(basemap, extent=basemap_extent)
plt.imshow(src.read(1), extent=src_extent, cmap=my_cmap, interpolation='none', clim=[-900, 1e5])
plt.show()
```

[image]